# What is the issue with Canadian tax regime?

Tags: canada, taxes

One of my cousins lives in Toronto, Canada. Her husband is an accountant who works in a private company. Last year, he was offered a promotion which he denied. According to him, he would have to pay more taxes, and as a result, his net income would decrease.

I don't have any means to talk to this person to ask about this problem. So, can you shed some light on this?

My younger brother is working in Canada. He said the employer is cutting $600 of his $2500 salary on the pretext of tax.

Can you explain?

Comment: Don't they have tax brackets in Canada ?

Comment: @audionuma, I don't know. I don't live in canada yet.

Comment: @audionuma they most definitely do: https://www.canada.ca/en/financial-consumer-agency/services/financial-toolkit/taxes/taxes-2/5.html

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Someone misunderstood something.

Comment: I've heard stories like this before. It was usually some bad employer gaslighting the person. it doesn't make any sense. The tax brackets are published for the federal and for the provincial part. It should be easy to calculate.

Comment: It's a bit embarrassing that an account is not able to solve it's own tax issues.

Comment: Beyond the tax brackets, could there be other benefits or tax deductions which would be reduced or not allowed at the higher salary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> According to him, he would have to pay more taxes, and as a result, his net income would decrease.

Your cousin's accountant husband has an incomplete understanding of Canada's taxation rules.

When your income reaches into the next tax bracket, it's not the *entire* income that is taxed at the higher rate. It's only the *portion* of the income that is above the previous tax bracket.

See [8.2.4 Tax brackets and rates](https://www.canada.ca/en/financial-consumer-agency/services/financial-toolkit/taxes/taxes-2/5.html) for complete information and examples.

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding in countries that use tax brackets.